# tmux and macOS Clipboard

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, tmux, macos-high-sierra

Is there a reliable way to make `tmux 2.5` to work with `macOS` clipboard?

After upgrading to 2.5 everything went downhill. I have tried every solution I have found and nothing works. Could anybody please provide me with a working sample of `tmux.conf` that will make it work?

I can copy from neovim inside `tmux` just fine. I can't copy the text using `tmux` itself.

Here is what I have in `.tmux.conf`:

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy" \; display-message "copied to system clipboard"
```

These are the errors that appear every time the session is started:

```
.tmux.conf:95: unknown command: begin-selection                
.tmux.conf:96: unknown command: copy-pipe-and-cancel
```

I have tried the following:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel pbcopy
```

I have also tried:

```
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel
```

Nothing.

Comment: could you get it to work ?

Comment: Yes, see the answer below

Answer (score 13):

I made it work with `tmux 2.6` like so:

Removed any references of `reattach-to-user-namespace` and now I have this in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
```

Comment: Do the words in your answer "Removed `reattach-to-user-namespace`" mean that you uninstalled the binaries for `reattach-to-user-namespace` (from https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard)?   Or is it that you removed the literal tokens `reattach-to-user-namespace` from your `.tmux.conf` file (i.e. you changed all literal instances of `"reattach-to-user-name-space pbcopy"` in your `.tmux.conf` to `"pbcopy"`)?

Comment: Removed from `.tmux.conf`, didn't bother uninstalling but it's not used anywhere in my dotfiles.

Answer (score 4):

Had a problem similar to yours.
Try reinstalling `reattach-to-user-namespace`

```
brew uninstall --force reattach-to-user-namespace
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace --with-wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste
```

the following works for me

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

Comment: what a waste of my bounty !

Comment: `--with-wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste` gives an error that it is invalid flag in Homebrew 3.5.6

Answer (score 3):

Here's mine. It uses vi mode keys:

```
# .tmux.conf
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel pbcopy
```

If you're using iTerm, make sure that you have "Applications in terminal may access clipboard" selected.

Comment: The problem is I have almost exactly this, here I have updated the question. Tried your variant - it doesn't work. I believe you have `tmux < 2.5`

Comment: You're missing the 'send -X' in your variant, otherwise I'm unsure.. I'm running 2.5.

Comment: Tried that as well. I have updated the post. Nothing. Works just fine from neovim inside tmux though.

Comment: Folks, try changing the second line to `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"`

Comment: As @TrevorOke mentioned, iTerm2 setting "Applications in terminal may access clipboard" is key!